# SpringMVC: @PathVariable value containing the plus (+) character

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have problem with @PathVariable in SpringMVC controller. Whenever I pass string containing plus ('+'), plus gets replaced by space. Encoding the parameter doesn't help.

So for example if I request url myapp/resend-validation/my+mail@gmail.com, I get "my mail@gmail.com" in my `email` variable. Same happens after requesting myapp/resend-validation/my%2Bmail@gmail.com

My controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resend-validation/{email:.+}")
public String resendValidation(@PathVariable String email, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) { 
    //controller code here
}
```

(the regular expresion in @RequestMapping's value is because of the dot in the email address, otherwise, value gets truncated after the dot. It doesn't affect my problem)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? I cannot reproduce this in `3.2.6.RELEASE`. When I request `myapp/resend-validation/my+mail@gmail.com` I get `my+mail@gmail.com` in the email variable (no space)

Comment: I can't reproduce it either with 4.0.0+. Works for 3.0.5 as well.

Comment: We are on Spring 3.1.3. I'll try to test other versions and fiddle with some special configuration we might be using. Thanks for reactions.

Comment: Have you tried invoking that URL with a + directly from a browser (by manually typing in the URL in the address bar)? My suspicion is that it might be due to encoding issues on the previous page, when it send the request...

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in my answer bellow, this was exactly the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me! It was error in completely different part. I'm calling the controller using Ajax with some javascript processing involved and the bug is there - it replaces 'plus' with 'space' and than calls the server. Thanks everyone for their time with this.